# How does Spring construct the objects it passes to its controller methods?

Tags: java, jquery, spring, spring-mvc

Sometimes code just explains things better than words, so I'll start with an example.  Suppose I have the following:

## Example:

A simple class `Bar`:

```java
public class Bar
{
    private String key;
    private String value;

    // getters and setters here!
}
```

Another simple class `Foo` containing a `List` of `Bar` objects:

```java
public class Foo
{
    private int id;
    private List<Bar> bars;

    // getters and setters here!
}
```

A Spring controller with the following method:

```java
@RequestMapping("/save")
public void save(Foo foo)
{
    // ...
}
```

A form on a webpage:

```html
<form id="awesome-form">
    <input name="id" value="42">
    <input name="bars[0].key" value="A">
    <input name="bars[0].value" value="B">
    <input name="bars[1].key" value="C">
    <input name="bars[1].value" value="D">
</form>
```

And some javascript which submits that form:

```js
$.post('/save', $('#awesome-form').serialize());
```

Which sends data which looks like this:

```
id=42&bars%5B0%5D.key=A&bars%5B0%5D.value=B&bars%5B1%5D.key=C&bars%5B1%5D.value=D
```

Which when URL decoded looks slightly more readable like this:

```
id=42&bars[0].key=A&bars[0].value=B&bars[1].key=C&bars[1].value=D
```

## Problem:

So what's the problem?  There is no problem!  (And that's the problem...)

This code correctly constructs the object you would expect (from looking at the form) which is then passed as `foo` to the `save` method.  This is all very intuitive, but I can't figure out why exactly it should work.  I've been been doing my fair share of googling, and read over a good portion of the [spring framework reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/) while focusing particularly on the [web MVC framework](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html), but I can't seem to find the section which explains the notation used by the form input names.

Of course it's intuitively clear that `bars[0].key` specifies the `key` field of the first element of the `bars` list of the `foo` object, but where is the documentation that says that this should be the case?

## Question:

Where can I find the documentation which explicitly specifies how the objects which are passed to controller methods in this manner are constructed?

Comment: You want the conversion service.

Comment: Perhaps this page helps you a bit: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data

Comment: @chrylis I understand that the conversion service can be used for converting simple objects to complex objects, like converting `String` to `Date`, but how does that relate to Spring's inherent ability to deserialize complex objects from x-www-form-urlencoded data?  Could you perhaps point me towards some specific documentation?

Comment: @john16384 Thank you for the link, but I do think that it only addresses how forms should be encoded (and how they end up as x-www-form-urlencoded data), but does not address specifically hows Java and Spring are able to deserialize this into objects.  Unless there is something I missed while browsing the link, in which case please do let me know.

Comment: All parameters start as `String` (or `String[]`). The conversion service tries to find a way to convert from `String` to the requested type.

Comment: @chrylis It does make sense that it uses the conversion service to convert from `String` to the requested type, since indeed, all of the data must start out as a `String`, but which mechanism in the conversion service specifically knows to attempt to take objects of an arbitrary type (like `Foo` in my example, as opposed to a previously known and simple to convert type like `Integer` or `Boolean`), and populate its properties as specified by the x-www-form-urlencoded `String`?  In either case I'm still having trouble locating where this process is specifically documented.

Comment: May be this will help you [https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#beans-beans](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#beans-beans)

Comment: @PavanKumarJorrigala I do believe that this is what I was looking for!  Thank you for your help!  Feel free to write it up as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Bean manipulation and the BeanWrapper](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#beans-beans)

Above link gives you some basic idea on how `BeanWrapper` converts `RequestParam` or `RequestBody`  to `Object`